# fopen / fgets using char* instead of FILE*, why does this work?

Tags: c

I noticed that I had used a `char*` variable instead of a `FILE*` variable in my code when using fopen and fgets, but my code works. I am wondering why this is? A section of my code is as follows.

```
...
char* filePath = ac->filepath;
char* line = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_CHAR_PER_LINE) ;
filePath = fopen(filePath, "r"); // we are assigning the result to a char*, not FILE*
if (filePath == NULL) {
    printf ("\n[%s:%d] - error opening file '%s'", __FILE__, __LINE__, filePath);
    printf ("\n\n");
    exit (1);
}

while ((fgets(line, MAX_CHAR_PER_LINE, filePath) != NULL)) {
...
```

Comment: It's still just a memory address, regardless of how it might be declared for data type.

Comment: Hmm, I see. . . this is bad form though, I should explicitly be using a *FILE variable, right?

Comment: Yes, you should change the data type to FILE*. The compiler will then be able to do a better job of verifying data types at compile time.

Comment: @RSinghS: Of course. Use a `FILE*` when it is needed, compile with warnings on, and life will be easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both a `char*` and a `FILE*` simply store a memory address. C has fairly weak typing (Edit: this was a misunderstanding on my part, see comments below) so it lets you assign pointers without worrying about the type they point to.

`fopen` returns the address of a `FILE` object and you store that address somewhere (in your case it is in a `char*`). When you use the address in `fgets` it still has the address of the `FILE` object so everything will work as expected.

Comment: "C has fairly weak typing so it lets you assign pointers without worrying about the type they point to." This is an error in C. This is accepted by some (most) compilers as an extension, but C itself does not allow it.

Comment: That's news to me! Can you give the section of the standard I should read up on?

Comment: Confusingly, it's part of 6.5.4 Cast operators, even though it applies to programs that *don't* cast: "Conversions that involve pointers, other than where permitted by the constraints of 6.5.16.1, shall be specified by means of an explicit cast." As indicated, 6.5.16.1 contains a list of pointer conversions that can be performed explicitly, and this isn't one of them. (Edit: actually, it isn't confusing, since 6.5.16.1 by itself is enough, 6.5.4 is not necessary.)

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler is very permissive. It should have complained that the FILE* to char* conversion is invalid.

Anyway, assuming the compiler accepts this implicit conversion, the answer is quite simple.
By the C standard, a char* and a void* pointer can hold, without loss, any pointer value.
So, you can convert from SOMETYPE* to char* and then, back from char* to SOMETYPE*, and you get the same pointer you initially had.
Actually, on most systems, all pointers are equivalent and you can freely convert from one to another.

FILE* is a small and opaque value of pointer type. Probably an actual pointer to an internal data structure, but this may be implemented differently (e.g. it might be a UNIX file descriptor converted to a pointer).
The STDIO functions just expect that you use the same opaque FILE* value you got from fopen, in fread/fwrite/fclose.

The FILE* is converted to char* when assigned to filePath.
The char* is converted to FILE* as the first parameter of fgets (again, your compiler should complain), and so, gets back to its initial value.

Suggestion: Use higher levels of errors/warnings in your compiler and fix your code.

Comment: Good answer. Welcome to SO!